# Cloud Code vs. Express

Tags: express, parse-platform, server, parse-cloud-code

I need to use a server for portions of my app. Since I'm using Express for this what is the benefit for using Cloud Code for aspects of my app that could be hosted on the server or in Parse Cloud Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Cloud Code for our mobile app is very useful now days.

there are following things that must know about Cloud Code

1.If your app is large then the code can be save on cloud so that our app take less time to load

Answer (score 1):

You can use both the server and cloud code for custom functions but each have there own purpose.

Cloud Code (the `main.js` file) is really more so for having custom API endpoints that have logic when they are called. Like changing one field for table changes another field.

The server part (all of the other files) is really for just hosing a website that uses express stuff and renders all your web pages using "`ejs`" or "`jade`".

I'm a bit new to parse but I hope this answers your question.